# ReactJS: fetch give error cannot read properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make an api call ( a get ) to download a document.

My problem is that when I make this api call I receive error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'payload')

```
const printPin = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    //....
    props.printedPin(scePersonaEntity.perCod, activateAlert)
}
```

**my reducer:**

```
export const printedPin= (id, callback) => {
  const requestUrl = `${apiUrl}/${id}/printpin`
  fetch(requestUrl)
    .then((response) => {
      response
        .blob()
        .then(blob => {
          console.log("blob ", blob)
          if (blob.type === 'application/problem+json') {
            callback();
          }
          else {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'pin.pdf';
            a.click();
          }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    })
}
```

In your opinion how can I fix this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `.then` chaining is incorrect.

Could you try this once?

```
 export const printedPin = (id, callback) => {
  const requestUrl = `${apiUrl}/${id}/printpin`
  fetch(requestUrl)
    .then((response) => response.blob()).then(blob => {
      console.log("blob ", blob)
      if (blob.type === 'application/problem+json') {
        callback();
      }
      else {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'pin.pdf';
        a.click();
      }
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

}
```

Your first then  will return `response.blob()` and next then will handle the response of the previous one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have correct the code as you suggest but I have the same error :(